# NGINX try_files odd behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm currently trying to integrate WordPress with an existing Laravel codebase.

I can access files in `/var/www/src/blog` directly, for instance, `site.com/blog/example.php` but I'm not able to access the `index.php` via `mysite.com/blog/`, so I'm unsure whether the issue is specific to my NGINX config or wordpress itself. Any help is much appreciated.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name ha_laravel.com;
    sendfile off;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ /blog/(.*)$ {
        root /var/www/src/blog;
        try_files /$1 /$1/ /index.php?$args;
        location ~ .*\/(.*php)$ {
                try_files /$1 /index.php?$args;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$1;
                fastcgi_cache off;
        }
    }
}
```

### Error Log

> ```
> 2015/08/02 11:20:15 [debug] 24131#0: *1529 test location: "/"
> 2015/08/02 11:20:15 [debug] 24131#0: *1529 test location: ~ "/blog/(.*)$"
> 2015/08/02 11:20:15 [debug] 24131#0: *1529 test location: ~ ".*\/(.*php)$"
> 2015/08/02 11:20:15 [debug] 24131#0: *1529 using configuration "/blog/(.*)$"
>
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 test location: "/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 test location: ~ "/blog/(.*)$"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 test location: ~ ".*\/(.*php)$"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 using configuration "/blog/(.*)$"
> ```

***Note: I omitted for readability, but the following was logged several time, presumably I somehow caused a loop?***

> ```
> internal error.
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 http cl:-1 max:1048576
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 rewrite phase: 3
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 post rewrite phase: 4
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 generic phase: 5
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 generic phase: 6
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 generic phase: 7
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 access phase: 8
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 access phase: 9
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 post access phase: 10
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 try files phase: 11
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 http script copy: "/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 http script capture: ""
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 trying to use file: "/" "/var/www/src/blog/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 http script copy: "/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 http script capture: ""
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 trying to use dir: "/" "/var/www/src/blog/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 try file uri: "/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 content phase: 12
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 open index "/var/www/src/blog/index.php"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 internal redirect: "/index.php?"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 rewrite phase: 1
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 test location: "/"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 test location: ~ "/blog/(.*)$"
> 2015/08/02 11:06:55 [debug] 24284#0: *1535 using configuration "/"
> ```

**Full log (in debug mode)**: http://pastebin.com/ZdZj40M1